# iOS How to Handle Parse JSON Push Notification when App is in Foreground

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform, webview

I have a very basic Webview app that I'm using Parse.com to send JSON push  notifications to.  I'm sending JSON push notification with a url to open in my web view like this:

```
{
"alert": "Push Title goes here",
"url": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

When I send the above message, if the app is closed or in the background it works by showing a banner notification and if you tap on the notification, it opens up our app and directs you to the specified url.

However, if the app is in the foreground, it just automatically loads the specified url with no interaction, which could be problematic if say they are in the middle of checking out and the pushed url takes them away from the checkout page unexpectedly.

Ideally, we'd like to have an alert pop up with the notification and the option to tap "view" to load the url, or to "close" which would just close the notification and allow the user to continue browsing the app where they were.

Here's what I currently have:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[Parse setApplicationId:@"XXX"
              clientKey:@"XXX"];

// Register for Push Notitications

UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];

// Override point for customization after application launch.

 self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
NSString *pushURL = [notificationPayload objectForKey:@"url"];

if (notification) {
    NSDictionary *aDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: pushURL forKey:@"urlToLoad"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoadRequestFromAppDel" object:Nil userInfo:aDict];
}

return YES;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSString *pushURL = [userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];

if (userInfo) {
    NSDictionary *aDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: pushURL forKey:@"urlToLoad"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoadRequestFromAppDel" object:Nil userInfo:aDict];
}

}
```

and here is my **ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(LoadRequestFromAppDel:) name:@"LoadRequestFromAppDel" object:Nil];

NSAssert(self.back, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'back'");
NSAssert(self.forward, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'forward'");
NSAssert(self.refresh, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'refresh'");
NSAssert(self.stop, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'stop'");
NSAssert(self.webView, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'webView'");

self.webView.delegate = self;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
[self updateButtons];
}

- (void)LoadRequestFromAppDel: (NSNotification*)aNotif
{
NSString *aStrUrl=[[aNotif userInfo] objectForKey:@"urlToLoad"];
NSURL* pushurl = [NSURL URLWithString:aStrUrl];
NSURLRequest* requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pushurl];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self updateButtons];
}
```

I'll also note that this is my first iOS app, so my knowledge is very limited but I've gotten this far..any more help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra method to your AppDelegate to receive the notifications when your app is running in the foreground. From Parse documentation:

> If your app is already running when the notification is received, the
>   data is made available in the
>   `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`
>   method through the `userInfo` dictionary.

see: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-responding-to-the-payload

Comment: Thanks Mo, I tried adding this to my AppDelegate and I'm able to receive my push notification when the app is in the foreground, however, it automatically loads the URL that I send in the payload.  What I'm trying to do is to provide an alert with 2 options, "View" which would then load the URL from the push notification, or "Close" which would just disregard the notification and they continue where they left off in the app.